# Доступ к свойству DBGridEh

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Помогите с кодом. Необходимо программно изменить свойство DBGridEh : *dgIndicator*, которое находится в разделе *Options*. Данная реализация этого куска кода:

> **DBGridEh1.Options['dgIndicator']:=True;**

Выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку, как и другие вариации, которые я использовал. Как же правильно написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options + [dgEditing];  // Adds dbEditing option

DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options - [dgEditing];  // Removes dbEditing option
```

Comment: @0xdb, подскажи, пожалуйста, как это делается

Comment: @0xdb, благодарю!

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616065/407561

Comment: Последний комментерий тут не нужен. Он ставится под вопросом, если вопрос переведён или он очень схожий.

Comment: @0xdb, как такового перевода не было, поэтому не стал добавлять Свободный перевод ответа.

Comment: Если перевода не было, то и  _Копипаст stackoverflow_ не стоило указывать (какая его смысловая нагрузка?). Почистим все комментарии, и  так хорошо.